# Syntax question about maple welcome here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

This question of mine about [maple](/questions/tagged/maple) syntax is [probably not welcome on math.stackexchange.com](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/do-we-actually-welcome-questions-about-software-that-mathematicians-use):

> "In Maple, `taylor(exp(x),x,2);` returns 1+x+O(x^2).  How can I
>   automatically convert this result to the same expression with the
>   O(x^2) terms removed?  I.e. something like
>   `removeBigO(taylor(exp(x),x,2));` to return 1+x?"

I'm wondering if the above question would be on-topic on SO. The FAQ and searches on meta about this aren't clear. The question basically comes down to whether or not syntax questions for computer algebra systems like [maple](/questions/tagged/maple) are considered "programming questions".

Is the above quoted question welcome on SO?

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65690/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-using-wolfram-mathematica) about [tag:mathematica] from before mathematica.stackexchange.com is related but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: mathematica must be renamed to mathapps to support Tora, Maple and other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently 139 questions tagged [maple](/questions/tagged/maple).  Go for it.

Comment: Thanks. [Here's for trying.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072194/how-can-i-programatically-truncate-order-o-terms-in-maple) A non-negative score there, and your answer is accepted.

Comment: [You were right: I even got a simple answer. Thanks!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072194/how-can-i-programatically-truncate-order-o-terms-in-maple)