# What is the difference between Mathematics Stack Exchange and Mathematica Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

While [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) exists, I discovered that there's another Stack Exchange website called [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), that has a very similar name to the other website. Both of these Stack Exchange websites seem to be on the topic of math, but what are the exact differences between them?

Comment: One is about math, one is about [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)

Comment: In general, if you're ever unsure what a specific exchange site is about you can go to their Help Center > "What topics can I ask about here?" article and that will explain.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118058/282094

Comment: The *About* page (now called "Tour", with "/tour" appended to the URL) on every Stack Exchange site is not always very informative, but [in this case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) it says *"Mathematica Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Wolfram [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica) and the Wolfram Language."*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica) is a distinct programming language/platform. The site *isn't* for math - and you can find out more about the site's scope in [their help center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

We do have two maths sites - [and you can find the difference between the two - Mathematics and MathOverflow here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251476/what-is-the-intended-difference-between-mathoverflow-and-mathematics/361553#361553), but Mathematica is not one of them.